# Для гуру frontend'a, неровный край блока

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

[image: Форма отправки]

**Подскажите ниндзи фронтенды.
Как сделать такую форму.**

Я перепробовал многие варианты svg, border, не получается.
Вариант с картинкой в бэкграунд не рассматривается.

Comment: Нарисовать в canvas?

Comment: нужен responsive ещё, canvas подойдет?

Comment: Почему не рассматривается вариант с картинкой? Это ведь будет работать во всех браузерах, в то время, canvas поддерживают не все используемые браузеры: http://professorweb.ru/my/html/html5/level4/4_4.php

Comment: Планируется нагруженный проект, слишком много таких блоков и каждый чуток отличается изгибами. Поэтому может canvas но я с ним не работал не знаю как он себя будет вести в бутстрап грид??

Comment: border-image (см. напр. http://css-live.ru/articles-css/razbiraemsya-s-border-image-iz-css3.html) не подойдет?

Comment: Надо разобраться ещё не совсем понятно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы сделал всё фоновыми картинками, с помощью [спрайта](http://habrahabr.ru/post/159027/), если у вас их много разных.

В бутстрап-грид по идее никаких проблем с canvas не будет, для будстрапа canvas слабо отличается от div или p. Можете использовать этот вариант